# Can I convert a boot disk from BIOS to EFI (UEFI)?

Tags: linux, bios, uefi, mbr, efi

I have a BIOS MBR (Linux) on my NVME - it works fine.

I'm now trying to enable *SAM* (or *Resizable BAR*) and in order to do so I have to disable *Compatibility Support Module* (CSM - i.e. BIOS) from my motherboard ([ASRock Taichi x570](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/x570%20taichi/#FAQ)).

The challenge is that if I do the same, my NVME doesn't get identified as bootable device of course.

Is there a way on Linux to convert the MBR from BIOS to EFI (or UEFI)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is https://superuser.com/questions/984294/converting-bios-mode-arch-linux-to-uefi of any help?

Comment: EFI isn’t a partition schema your thinking of GPT

Comment: @Ramhound Indeed, that shows my knowledge is a bit flaky... that should be the right way to express my question.

Comment: If your question is unclear or contains inaccurate information you can edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out can be done - but is quite a potentially cumbersome process. The main suggestion is to format and reinstall Linux.